# Wordpress custom theme no content

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to develop a new wordpress theme for learning theme development. So i followed wordpress blog finally had my version of theme. When I test my theme locally its working fine but when upload the same on wordpress the body is gone and wont show anything except the footer. I am using jquery and javascript for the body.

Header:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * The header for our theme.
     *
     * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
     *
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
     */

    ?><!DOCTYPE html>
    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
        <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
```

index.php:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * The main template file.
     */
    get_header(); ?>
    <div class="content">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                $html = '<div id="pscanvas" class="row">
                 <div  class="row__inner ">';

                // The Query
                query_posts( array ('orderby' => 'date' ) );

                // The Loop
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $imgurl=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() );
                $posturl= get_permalink();
                $title=get_the_title();
                    $html .='<a href="'. $posturl .'" class="tile">';
                    $html .= '<div class="tile__media">';

                    $html .='<img class="tile__img" src="'. $imgurl.'"/>';
                    $html .='</div><div class="tile__details"><div class="tile__title">';
                    $html .= ''. $title .'</div></div></a>';        
                } 
                endwhile;
                // Reset Query
                wp_reset_query();
                $html .= '</div></div>';
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!--.content-->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    <?php wp_footer(); // Crucial footer hook! ?>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

footer.php

```
    <footer class="footer">
        <p>And this is the footer</p>
    </footer>
    <?php wp_footer(); // Crucial core hook! ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

style.css

```
    /*
    Theme Name: Custom theme
    Description: My Basic theme.
    Version: 1.0.0
    License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
    License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
    */
    body {
        font-family: arial, helvetica, verdana;
        font-size: 0.8em;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .header {
        background-color: #1be;
        margin-left: 14%;
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0.1em;
        border-color: #999;
        border-style: solid;
        width: 72%;
        height: 250px;
    }

    .content {
        background-color: #999;
        margin-left: 14%;
        margin-top: 5px;
        float: left;
        width: 46%;
        border-width: 0.1em;
        border-color: #999;
        border-style: solid;
    }

    .sidebar {
        background-color: #1d5;
        margin-right: 14%;
        margin-top: 5px;
        float: right;
        border-width: 0.1em;
        border-color: #999;
        border-style: solid;
        top: 180px;
        width: 23%;
    }

    .footer {
        background-color: red;
        margin-left: 14%;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 5px;
        width: 72%;
        height: 50px;
        border-width: 0.1em;
        border-color: #999;
        border-style: solid;
    }
    h1,
    p {
        text-align: center;
    }

    p {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .row {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .row__inner {
        transition: 450ms transform;
        font-size: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
        margin: 70.3125px 0;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .tile {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 250px;
        height: 140.625px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        font-size: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: 450ms all;
        transform-origin: center left;
    }

    .tile__img {
        width: 250px;
        height: 140.625px;
        object-fit: cover;
    }

    .tile__details {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        font-size: 10px;
        opacity: 0;
        background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
        transition: 450ms opacity;
    }
    /*
    before hover content is null
    */
    .tile__details:after,
    .tile__details:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        display: #000;
    }

    .tile__details:after {
        margin-top: -25px;
        margin-left: -25px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 3px solid #ecf0f1;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 100%;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    /*
    play button overlay on hover
    */
    .tile__details:before {
        content: '\25B6';
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 30px;
        color:#ffffee;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: -25px;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .tile:hover .tile__details {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .tile__title {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    color:#ffffee;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .row__inner:hover {
        transform: translate3d(-125px, 0, 0);
    }

    .row__inner:hover .tile {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }

    .row__inner:hover .tile:hover {
        transform: scale(2);
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .tile:hover ~ .tile {
        transform: translate3d(250px, 0, 0);
    }
```

I believe the php is not getting parsed or something. But since I am a beginner, I am unable to debug. The front page should display all featured posts and it is working fine locally. Please help.

Comment: Is it showing the div `<div id="pscanvas" class="row">`?

Comment: yes it is and the inner_row div tag as well but no content inside.

Comment: Do your posts have featured images attached to them?  It appears that the title of the post will only be displayed if the post has a thumbnail.

Comment: yes they have. I have modifies the query to fetch  10 posts. query_posts( array ('post_type' => 'post','orderby' => 'date','order' => 'ASC','posts_per_page' => 10 ) ) its working fine now. It seems the quer returns only one post by default. Although my local was returning all .Thanks a lot.